# Use __init__ to set attribute

Tags: python, class, init

I'm trying pygame for a simple game. I want to have a class `Player` so that I can simply make a second or third player.

I want the player to have some attribute like HP. So my code is

```
class Player():
    HP=100
    Speed=5
    ICON=pygame.image.load('somepic.ipg')
```

But later I want players to have different icons or HP so I tried

```
class Player():

    def __init__(self,HP,ICON):
    self.HP=HP
    self.ICON=ICON
```

My code was like:

```
P1=Player(80,someicon) 
P1.HP=P1.HP-damage
```

and something like this. But then I got

```
AttributeError P1 doesn't have attribute.HP
```

I read the doc of `__init__` but I don't understand why it's not working. I know I can use:

```
P1=Player()
P1.HP=80
P1.ICON=someicon
```

But I want to know more about class and `__init__`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The Tutorial may be a good place to start - [9. Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes)

Comment: Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

In your init method you have not indented the lines under the function def.   The self.* assignments should be indented further.

Comment: Thank you but it's a failure when I typed here. it was right when I used them.

Comment: I tried your code (with corrected indent) in jupyter notebook.   looked like i got the expected result and no error like you got.  might be code missing in your example?